# What is the purpose of Dockerfile command "Volume"?

Tags: docker, containers, dockerfile, docker-volume, docker-image

When a Dockerfile contains VOLUME instruction (say) `VOLUME [/opt/apache2/www, ...]` (hope this path exists in real installation), it means this path is going to be mounted to something (right?). And this VOLUME instruction is for the image and not for one instance of it (container) but for every instance.

Anyway irrespective of whether an image contains a VOLUME defined or not, at the time of starting a container the run command can create a volume by mapping a local host path to a container path.

```
docker run --name understanding_volumes -v /localhost/path1:/opt/apache2/www -v /localhost/path2:/any/container/path image_name
```

The above should make it clear that though `/any/container/path` is not defined as a VOLUME in Dockerfile, we are able to mount it while running container.

That said, this SOF question throws some light on it - [What is the purpose of defining VOLUME mount points within DockerFile rather than adhoc cmd-line -v?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33148754/what-is-the-purpose-of-defining-volume-mount-points-within-dockerfile-rather-tha). Here one benefit of VOLUME instruction is mentioned. Which is, other containers can benefit from it. Using the `--from-container` (could not find this option for `docker run --help`, not sure if the answer meant `--volumes-from`) Anyway thus the mount point is accessible to other container in some kind of automatic way. Great.

My first question is, is the other volume path `/any/container/path image_name` mounted on to the container **understanding_volumes** also available to the second container using  `--from-container` or `--volumes-from` (whichever option is correct)?

My next question is, is the use of VOLUME instruction just to let the other containers link to this path --> that is to make the data on `/opt/apache2/www` available to other containers through easy linking. So it's just sharing out. Or is there any data that can be made available to first container too.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Defining a volume in a Dockerfile has the advantage of specifying the volume location inside the image definition as documentation from the image creator to the user of the image. That's just about the only upside.

It was added to docker very early on, quite possibly when data containers were the only way to persist data. We now have a solution for named volumes that has obsoleted data containers. We have also added the compose file to define how containers are run in an easy to understand and reuse syntax.

While there is the one upside of self documented images, there are quite a few downsides, to the point that **I strongly recommend against defining a volume inside the image** to my clients and anyone publishing images for general reuse:

1. The volume is forced on the end user, there's no way to undefine a volume in the image.
2. If the volume is not defined at runtime (with a `-v` or compose file), the user will see anonymous volumes in their `docker volume ls` that have no association to what created them. These are almost always useless wastes of disk space.
3. They break the ability to extend the image since any changes to a volume in an image after the `VOLUME` line are typically ignored by docker. This means a user can never add their own initial volume data, which is very confusing because docker gives no warning that it is ignoring the user changes during the image build.
4. If you need to have a volume as a user a runtime, you can always define it with a `-v` or compose file, even if that volume is not defined in the Dockerfile. Many users have the misconception that you must define it in the image to be able to make it a named volume at runtime.

The ability to use `--volumes-from` is unaffected by defining the volume in the image, but I'd encourage you to avoid this capability. It does not exist in swarm mode, and you can get all the same capabilities along with more granularity by using a named volume that you mount in two containers.

Comment: The upside to VOLUME forcing the creation of the volume comes from apps that don't perform on the overlay type file systems commonly used in containers.  Most databases images need to use it otherwise they perform horribly.

Comment: If you don't define your volume for a database at runtime, so that it doesn't get lost in a sea of anonymous volumes, then performance will be there least of your concerns, rather data loss would be the problem there. Defining it as a volume breaks users that want to extend the image with an initial db setup.

Comment: If you don't define a volume at runtime then you should expect data to be ephemeral, that's standard. Although for some reason docker decided when they added named volumes to make `VOLUME` volumes slightly less ephemeral than data in the container by keeping the volume around in a hard to link state??

Comment: Anyway, just trying to note the one small upside when they are used properly, like the `mysql`, `postgres` and `mongo` images that provide initialisation as a feature and save's a lot of trouble for the common use case of devs `docker run`